# Knight's Tour recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, knights-tour

Is anyone able to find a mistake in my `knight's tour code`? I can't seem to find it, and I'm getting an infinite loop, not a stack overflow

```
private bool heuristic(int[,] board, int x, int y, ref int jmp)
{
    if (x < 0 || x > 7 || y < 0 || y > 7 || board[x, y] > 0)
        return false;
    board[x, y] = ++jmp;
    if (jmp == 64)
        return true;

    if (heuristic(board, x + 2, y + 1, ref jmp) ||
        heuristic(board, x + 2, y - 1, ref jmp) || heuristic(board, x - 2, y + 1, ref jmp) ||
        heuristic(board, x - 2, y - 1, ref jmp) || heuristic(board, x + 1, y + 2, ref jmp) ||
        heuristic(board, x + 1, y - 2, ref jmp) || heuristic(board, x - 1, y + 2, ref jmp) ||
        heuristic(board, x - 1, y - 2, ref jmp))
        return true;
    board[x, y] = 0;
    jmp--;
    return false;
}
```

And calling it:

```
var board = new int[8,8];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var jmp = 0;
var result = heuristic(board, x, y, ref jmp);
```

I need to have a `jmp` variable as I'm preforming multiple trials and also want to show the path taken.
Thanks!

Comment: How sure are you that it is an infinite loop, and not just taking a very, very long time?

Comment: @JohnBurger  It's an 8x8 board.

Comment: @Stefan That doesn't answer the question.. :) Can you please provide the starting conditions, so that people can reproduce the code? That is, the intial array, `x`, `y`, and `jmp`?

Comment: You've got eight recursive calls, each of which could go 63 deep. 8^63 is a very, very large number. I know that by no means every call will go that deep - but they start out with a huge number of options before getting "cornered" by previous visits.

Comment: @Rob everything is 0, including the initialmatrix, filled with 0's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour):

> There are 26,534,728,821,064 [...] tours

and

> A brute-force search for a knight's tour is impractical on all but the smallest boards; for example, on an 8x8 board there are approximately 4×10<sup>51</sup> possible move sequences, and it is well beyond the capacity of modern computers (or networks of computers) to perform operations on such a large set. However, the size of this number gives a misleading impression of the difficulty of the problem, which can be solved "by using human insight and ingenuity ... without much difficulty."

Comment: Divide and conquer? Warnsdorf's rule? Check the WIkipedia article I linked. There have been *PhD* s written on how best to do this...

Comment: Warnsdorf's rule seems to be: for each possible next location, check how many places are reachable from *there* (in other words, only go two deep). Then choose the one with the *least* number of future options. If nothing else it'll prevent a full depth-first search...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I read about this on Wikipedia but for some reason I didn't expect that an 8x8 board would go that deep in DFS. I switched the recursive calls to do it in clockwise direction and it solves it quickly. I'll add the Warnsdorff's rule.